# Layout_weight does not work properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-weight

I have the followin xml where I want imageview and then two textview and then imageview again, but it does not work properly.

Here is what I planned to have:

[image]

Here is what I am getting:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
     android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
     android:paddingTop="5dp"
     android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <com.example.eyeniaras.satdostum.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                app:civ_border_width="0.2dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/dark"
                android:id="@+id/userImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text = "45 days ago"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userClick"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:background="@drawable/list_arrow" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, that doesn't work-  what does it do?  Its easiest to fix it if we know how its failing

Comment: place image view inside `LinearLayout` and apply weight on that `LinearLayout`

Comment: change linearlayout height to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside linearlayout must have 0 width

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:layout_weight="60">
```

Comment: yeah width must be 0dp to apply weight property.

Comment: no when you add weight and set the width to 0, it changes its width based on parent layout width and other elements weight. its orientation changes the element inside

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Comment: can you explain which space you mean? @texas

Answer (score 1):

it is because of width make it 0dp..copy the bellow code it works perfect

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
        android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                      <com.example.eyeniaras.satdostum.CircleImageView
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                        app:civ_border_width="0.2dp"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/dark"
                        android:id="@+id/userImage"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                       <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="100"
                        android:layout_weight="60">

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/userName"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="0dp"
                               android:layout_gravity="center"
                               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                               android:background="#ffffff"
                               android:textSize="18sp"
                               android:textStyle="bold"
                               android:layout_weight="50"/>

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="0dp"
                               android:layout_gravity="center"
                               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                               android:background="#ffffff"
                               android:textSize="18sp"
                               android:text = "45 days ago"
                               android:textStyle="bold"
                               android:layout_weight="50"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                      <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/userClick"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:background="@drawable/list_arrow" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Explain to him what was the mistake he made, teach a man how to fish rather than just giving him the fish

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Comment: use gravity in center attribute for textview and give hardcoded height to your main layout

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **android:layout_weight** for both images and textview so here is solution,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.4">

        <com.example.eyeniaras.satdostum.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/userImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/dark"
            app:civ_border_width="0.2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hi"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="45 days ago"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/list_arrow"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Comment: you need to set that according to your image size just chage layout_weight

Comment: Is this for single device or you want to support to all device with different resolutions ?

Comment: I want all device support with different resolutions as well

Comment: okay. then you have to create diffent layout files and different size images than copy my answer code and try.

Comment: different layout files?

Comment: If you dont want that than you can use Fixed height android:layout_height="100dp" in topmost LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Inside linearlayout second chance follow code.

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="60">
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**i was changed your code check it**

**change image View as you require and replace your code with this**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:weightSum="100"
android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/userImage"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="60">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="hey hi"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="50"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text = "45 days ago"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="50"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userClick"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:layout_weight="20"  /></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use The following Code:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use weightsum at all and then assign weight according to requirement to all main views.It will definitely work.why to make things complex.I have done it for you.Check it below.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
  android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

              <com.example.eyeniaras.satdostum.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                app:civ_border_width="0.2dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/dark"
                android:id="@+id/userImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

               <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_weight="0.6">

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/userName"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="0dp"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                       android:background="#ffffff"
                       android:textSize="18sp"
                       android:textStyle="bold"
                       android:layout_weight="1"/>

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="0dp"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                       android:background="#ffffff"
                       android:textSize="18sp"
                       android:text = "45 days ago"
                       android:textStyle="bold"
                       android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userClick"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@drawable/list_arrow" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Comment: No one knows what is written in.. com.example.eyeniaras.satdostum.CircleImageView...also don't use   android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"  use   android:src="@drawable/circle_shape"...background makes images blur.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect scenario to make use of [PercentageRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). The best thing about this layout is that you can use **percentage based dimensions** which is super easy.

Here is a quick example of it,

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

This is very simple and intuitive to use and is optimized for various use cases too.

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Comment: @texas It is in the support library and is backward compatible to API 7.

Comment: Could you please illustrate my example based on PercentRelativeLayout in order to see bigger picture?

Comment: You can try it yourself.  It is super simple to use. If you face any problem, post your code, I will help you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your code and stripped it down. The following, at least in studio design, has the layout you've described. Perhaps progressively change/adapt this; checking as you go along that it maintains the desired layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
    android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_weight="60">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text = "45 days ago"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userClick"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note I've done away with things like `width="match_parent"`, which may have been an issue, as an example.

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Answer (score 1):

According to Image.

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.example.eyeniaras.satdostum.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/userImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/dark"
            app:civ_border_width="0.2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="45 days ago"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="45 days ago"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/list_arrow"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. There is huge spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:layout_weight="60">
```

android:layout_width="match_parent",this layout's width is match_parent,so it filled up everything else,change to wrap_content,just like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/userProfileDetail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="userProfileDetailAction"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/userImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="46 days ago"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userRegistrationDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="45 days ago"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/userImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use can following thing for weight ..i think this answer is helpful for you.. [image: xml image]
    this xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/images" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Firstname" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lastname" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/download" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

and this code for background past in drawable/background
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0.3dp"
        android:color="#797979" />`enter code here`
</shape>
```